# Javascript document loading event

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript document loading event which which will activate after: the html is loaded but the not displayed in the browser?

Comment: AFAIK the html is displayed as soon as it's received which is why you sometimes get really plain disorganized pages for a few seconds while the CSS catches up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is displayed as it loads, so no, there's not an event like that. Are you perhaps looking for something like jQuery's `$(document).ready()`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/ready)]</sup>* event?

If not that, then give us a little more context and we'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the HTML through an AJAX call and display it when you feel like it, but that would be a (slightly) more manual process.